# How to merge multiple functions and pass data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to merge two functions and get the output of one become the input for the other one.

First function dynamically reads data from database and returns an array of values [val, val2, val3, ...]. Data is updated by typing more and more characters into the input field. I would like the output of this function - this array to became the input parameter for the second function.

```js
var path = "{{ route('autocomplete') }}";

$('#search').typeahead({
  source:  function (query, process) {
    return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (data) {
      var arr = data.map(function(a) {return a.name_full;});

      console.log(arr);
      return arr;
    });
  }
});
```

Second function provides input field autocomplete functionality based on the staticaly defined array of values. I would like to replace this by the output of the first function.

```js
var haystack = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Small Talk", "Scheme"];

console.log(haystack);

$(function(){
  $('#search').suggest(haystack,{});
});
```

I hope to use the script as input field autocomplete function without dropdown.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/h0jtpj2z/6/)

Comment: Are you trying to use both [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) and [jQuery.suggest](https://polarblau.github.io/suggest/) at the same time?

Comment: You might want to check out `Promise.all()`

Comment: Rather than returning the result of the ajax call to another function which populates suggestions, why not populate suggestions within the $.get success callback?  Or pass a function that does the population as a callback to be run on success.

Comment: Yes, I am using both libraries at the same time. And they both work at the same time because while I am getting suggestions coming from the second function I also see data logged into the console coming from the first function.

Comment: @Karolko The libraries seem to both do the same thing (provide autocomplete suggestions). Is there a reason that you're trying to use both at the same time? Otherwise, doing a plain AJAX get (apart from typeahead) and calling `.suggest()` from the success handler seems easiest.

Comment: I tried the Promise.all() method and its working fine when myFunction returns a static array populated inside myFunction. But as soon as I try to populate it with the function returning results from DB, I get again the same error.

Comment: @AndrewMyers: Not sure what you mean at the same time. I thought JQuery.suggest is enhancing JQuery capability by providing the autocomplete capability **without dropdown**, which is what I want to achieve. I did not find a way how to achieve it with jquery library only.

Comment: [**FIDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/h0jtpj2z/6/)